# How to install a system made in python with kivymd and with a layered architecture?

Tags: python, android, installation, kivymd

I have recently been trying to install a mobile system made with python and kivymd with the "Layered Model" development architecture, the file organization looks like this:

[image]

The ads.py file is the main file that must be executed first in order to work
and the adstyle.kv file contains all the elements of the system design.

I have tried to use buildozer, pydroid, kivylauncher, pyinstaller and other types of applications but everything has been unsuccessful. How can I install a project like this on a cell phone?